# Weird white space between each React component

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm writing a small web app with multiple components. I've written the back end functionality, but I am receiving a strange problem in the styling.

Specifically speaking, a white space appears between each component and I can't figure out why. This only occurs between components, not all divs.

It is coming out like this:
[image: White space exists between the navbar and landing component, as well as every other component]

This is happening between each component and I am pulling my hair out over it. I've removed any imported css files and the problem still persists. I've also tried removing components one by one but the problem still persists.

App.Js, the main file is quite long with many functions and components, so I've just included what I am returning:

**App.JS:**

```
return (
    <div>
      <NavBar
      defaultAccount = {defaultAccount}
      />
      <Landing
        defaultAccount= {defaultAccount}
        connectWalletHandler = {connectWalletHandler}
      />
      <Form
        optionValues = {optionValues}
        removeFormFields = {removeFormFields}
        handleOptionChange = {handleOptionChange}
        addFormFields = {addFormFields}
        setQuestion = {setQuestion}
        handleSubmitPoll = {handleSubmitPoll}
      />
      <Polls
        pollList={pollList}
        handleVote={handleVote}
      /> 
      {errorMessage}
    </div>
  );
```

I am pulling my hair out here, has this happened to anyone else?

I have tried removing the CSS. I've removing each component. I've checked to see if white spaces exist between tags in each component. But a whitespace still exists between each component

Comment: Welcome to SO, please could you edit your question and use the snippet button to add your html and css to create a [mcve] otherwise it will be impossible for us to guess what your problem is

Comment: It's most likely going to be a [collapsing margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) problem though - probably from your heading

Comment: Hi @Pete thanks for the response. As I mentioned, removing the CSS does not solve the problem as when I inspect each element the whitespace will still appear. I will add it now and a snippet link however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented from @Pete, it was a margin collapsing problem. Adding

> overflow:auto

to the elements involved with the collapse seems to have fixed it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).